# Change directory from python script for calling shell

Tags: python, bash, cd, subshell

I would like to build a python script, which can manipulate the state of it's calling bash shell, especially it's working directory for the beginning.

With `os.chdir` or `os.system("ls ..")` you can only change the interpreters path, but how can I apply the comments changes to the scripts caller then?

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: Can you provide some more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that directly from python, as a child process can never change the environment of its parent process.

But you can create a shell script that you *source* from your shell, i.e. it runs in the same process, and in that script, you'll call python and use its output as the name of the directory to `cd` to:

```
/home/choroba $ cat 1.sh
cd "$(python -c 'print ".."')"
/home/choroba $ . 1.sh
/home $
```

Comment: Very interesting idea, cool - thank you :) Maybe it is not possible by "normal"  calls to change the environment of its parent process, but is there maybe some way of exposeing the resources of the parent process to its child?